# Having Trouble using file_get_contents($url) when $url is a variable

Tags: php, json, google-maps, variables, file-get-contents

I have a simple script which uses `file_get_contents($url);` to output a JSON array.  The script works fine when I load a static link like so:

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true’);
```

But I am trying to build a more dynamic link to reference and so I am initially building the link with a PHP script and assigning is to the `$url` variable.

When I do this I get:

`Warning: file_get_contents(http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true’) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in ../myfile.php on line 32`

This also has to do with the way I am building the `$url` variable:

`$url='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$latRefDef.$lat.', '.$longRefDef.$long.'&sensor=true';`

I know this because I can place a static value in for the link and it will perform as expected.  Any idea where I could be off?

Comment: This question is about a syntax error that is unlikely to help others.

Comment: You have a **'** in your constructed `$url`, maybe this is because you use **'** rather than **"**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a "smart quote" apostrophe at the end.  Replace it with a real one.

You also need to get rid of the space after your comma in the url.